# Mobile website shows incorrect weekly/monthly reputation

Tags: bug, reputation, mobile-web, tabs

On mobile, if I search users by `?tab=reputation&filter=[week][month][quarter][year]`, the users are listed properly for the respective filters, in proper order of rep gained in that time period, but their **reputation shown is their all-time rep**. It should show the rep earned during that time period.

[image]
  [image]

Comment: Are you sure @shog9 didn't gain 223k rep this week? How do you know he's not a Skeet?

Comment: @euphoria [On the full site, it shows the proper amount.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week) :P